# Do variables initialized in C header files only get allocated once when a function from that header file is called from Haskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-ffi

Assuming that every source c file using a variable initialized in a C header file is declared using `extern`, that variable should be only allocated once no matter how many times a function defined in a source c file including that header and declaring that variable with `extern` is called.

So I'm referring to one way to ensure that constants used between functions defined in separate files are not allocated for every call to any function that uses that constant.

Now when i call a function in a header file under these conditions using the Haskell FFI, I would like to know if calling functions declared in that header file allocates that variable repeatedly or if it's allocated once. And if its not allocated only once, are there any simple ways to make sure it is?

Here's an example of the .hs, .h, and .c files.

Main.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Main (main) where

foreign import ccall unsafe "cstuff.h cfnc"
  cfnc :: IO ()

main :: IO ()
main = do cfnc
          cfnc 
          cfnc
```

cstuff.h:

```
extern int myvar; 
void cfnc();
```

cstuff.c:

```
#include "cstuff.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int myvar = 1;
void cfnc() {
   printf("%i\n",myvar);
}
```

So in this case cfnc was called was called 3 times and I would like to know if `myvar` is only allocated once or 3 times. And if its not only once what can i do to make sure it's only allocated once?

Comment: `int myvar; myvar = 1; ` should be `int myvar = 1; ` and in the .c file. `extern int myvar;` should be in the .h file.

Comment: You could print the address of the variable using `%p` in `printf("%p", &myvar)` (with `&`) to see if it changes. I didn't try it but I assume the allocation happens only one time, do you have reasons to believe this is not the case?

Comment: @chi I now changed it to `int myvar = 1;`. But i don't think its correct to switch the extern like you suggest. From my understanding `extern` means `myvar` is defined elsewhere. If i define it in the c file then `myvar` would be allocated when `cfnc` is called.

Comment: @Marjin Thanks I'll try that. If it does change then I'll know for sure this can happen. But if it doesn't I still won't know if the compiler optimized it away in this specific case. I'm not sure how to prevent the compiler from optimizing it away to check that for sure. Do you know?

Comment: If you define it as a global variable, it should be allocated once on program startup. C allows multiple declarations of variables (with `extern`), but only one definition (e.g. `int x =1;`) in the whole program. To comply with this, typically one uses `extern` in the header, so that it can be #included many times, but makes a single .c file define the variable.

Comment: @chi Okay I see. As long as i declare it as a global variable in the c file, what you said should be correct?

Comment: Yes, you have to _define_ it (not just declare it) in a single C file. Definitions of variables are those without `extern`. Declarations also include those with `extern`. (For functions, it's different -sigh-, but it does not matter here)

Comment: @chi sorry yes i meant define it as a global variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you mean by allocated, it may in fact be allocated zero times! Check it out:

```
% objdump -t Main | grep myvar
00000000004a8418 g     O .data  0000000000000004              myvar
```

That `00000000004a8418` is the address that's been set aside, once and for all before the program even starts, to hold `myvar`. (The `0000000000000004` is how many bytes have been set aside -- just right for an `int` on my machine.) Here's evidence (though not proof) that's what it means. Changing `cfnc` to be

```
void cfnc() {
   printf("%i\n%p\n",myvar,&myvar);
}
```

the new output I get from running your program is:

```
1
0x4a8418
1
0x4a8418
1
0x4a8418
```

As you say, this is only evidence, not proof -- e.g. perhaps the compiler has done something clever. But no; not only did I run the compiler without optimizations turned on, this is also just the bog-standard thing that every C compiler I know of does for top-level variables.